# Run Powershell command in macro as Admin (Elevated)

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have written some code that runs in a macro. Somehow the code runs the Powershell command (which is calc.exe), so specifically, I want to run the command as admin (elevated)? Can someone help me?

This is the code

```
Sub Auto_Open()
        o
End Sub

Sub AutoOpen()
        o
End Sub

Sub Document_Open()
        o
End Sub

Public Function o() As Variant
        Dim fSfv As String
        fSfv = "powershell calc.exe"
        Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 0
        strComputer = "."
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
        Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
        objConfig.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW
        Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
        objProcess.Create fSfv, Null, objConfig, intProcessID
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fSfv = "powershell -command Start-Process -Verb RunAs calc.exe"
```

Running a command elevated in PowerShell requires use of the [`Start-Process` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with parameter `-Verb RunAs`.

Additionally, consider inserting `-NoProfile` before `-command` to suppress the (here unnecessary) loading of PowerShell's profile files.